# NodeJs Performance.getEntriesByType() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to measure performance and output performance measures by using performance.getEntriesByType() however getting back an error that performance.getEntriesByType() is not a function. Tried different troubleshooting however anything I tried results in the same error, don't really understand how getEntriesByType() is not a function as it comes from a node dependency. Node version I am using is : 10.22.1 not using any npm packages pure NodeJs code.

```
var {performance} = require('perf_hooks');
var util = require('util');
var debug = util.debuglog('performance');


handlers._tokens.post = function (data, callback){
performance.mark('entered function')
var phone = typeof(data.payload.phone) == 'string' && data.payload.phone.trim().length > 10 ? data.payload.phone.trim() : false
var password = typeof(data.payload.password) == 'string' && data.payload.password.trim().length > 0 ? data.payload.password.trim() : false
performance.mark('inputs validated')

if (phone && password){
    performance.mark('beginning user lookup')
    _data.read('users', phone, function(err, userData){
        performance.mark('user lookup complete')
        if(!err && userData){
            // hash the password and validate
            performance.mark('beginning password hashing')
            hashedPassword = helpers.hash(password)
            performance.mark('password hashing complete')
            if (hashedPassword == userData.hashedPassword) {
                // if valid create token
                performance.mark('creating data for token')
                var tokenId = helpers.createRandomString(20)
                // set expiry date
                var expires = Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60
                var tokenObject = {
                    'phone': phone,
                    'id': tokenId,
                    'expires': expires
                }
                performance.mark('token data creation complete')
                performance.mark('beginning storing token data')
                // store the token
                _data.create('tokens', tokenId, tokenObject, function(err){
                    performance.mark('token data storing is complete')
                    //  gather all the measurements
                    performance.measure('Beginning to end', 'entered function', 'token data storing is complete')
                    performance.measure('Password hasing', 'beginning password hashing', 'password hashing complete')
                    performance.measure('Finding user', 'beginning user lookup', 'user lookup complete')
                    performance.measure('Input validation', 'entered function', 'inputs validated')
                    performance.measure('Token creation', 'creating data for token', 'token data creation complete')
                    performance.measure('Token storing', 'beginning storing token data', 'token data storing is complete')

                    //  log out all the measurements
                    var measurements = []
                    measuerments = performance.getEntriesByType('measure')
                    measurements.forEach((measurement)=>{
                        debug('\x1b(33m%s\x1b(0m', measurement.name + ' ' + measurement.duration)
                    })
                    if(!err){
                        callback(200, tokenObject)
                    } else {
                        callback(500, {'error': 'couldnt create new token'})
                    }
                })
            }   else {
                callback(400, {'error': 'passwords did not match'})
            }
        }   else {
            callback(400, {'error': 'couldnt find the user'})
        }
    })

}   else {
    callback(400, {'error': 'missing required fields'})
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_class_perf_hooks_performanceobserver):

You need to create a `PerformanceObserver` and in its call back, you get a `PerformanceObserverEntryList` on which you can call `getEntriesByType()`

```js
const {
  performance,
  PerformanceObserver
} = require('perf_hooks');

const obs = new PerformanceObserver((list, observer) => {
  console.log(list.getEntriesByType('measure'));
  observer.disconnect();
});
obs.observe({ entryTypes: ['measure'], buffered: true });

performance.measure('test');
```

(the code example is also taken from the documentation and slightly adapted to OP's question)